# Utitlsing QGIS and Stata's spwmatrix command

Tags: qgis, stata

At present I’m working on a paper which analyses the impact diversity can have on employment amongst Irish regions. Given the data which this study uses are based on administrative boundaries, we wish to employ a spatial model.
The data is panel in nature with a T = 6 and n = 27.

Originally, I was utilising the user written command xsmle provided by Belotti et al. (2016) and the model of choice was a Spatial Durbin Model. 
However, these set of commands are limited to a finite number of spatial panel models.

For instance, I would like to estimate a Spatial Durbin Error Model. 
What I would like to do is create spatially lagged independent variables (using spalgvar) , and then include these variables into an Spatial Error Model to estimate a Spatial Durbin Error Model.

I’m aware that  the spwmatrix command was updated with the xtw(#) option in order to allow users to generate spatial weights for panel data. 
I’m running into some issues in trying to specify my weights matrix with the spwmatrix command.

I’ve attached the code sample for ease

As you can see I run into no difficulties with the spmat command however, I’m unclear how to carry out an identical specification for the spwmatrix command (note I would require to specify a panel as my data is panel).

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte(v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21 v22 v23 v24 v25 v26 v27 v28)
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
end
*Creating a matrix with spmat 
putmata W = (v*), replace
m rowsum(W)
spmat dta v v*, replace normalize(row)
spmat summarize v, links
*How to create the matrixh with spwmatrix? 
spwmatrix socio v*, wname(r) row wtype(socecon) xtw(6)
///error too many variables specified
```

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Anyone with any experience of this? Have searched the internet, unfortunately with no luck.